# liveui of videojs seeking is not working on Chrome browser of android

Tags: http-live-streaming, video.js

```
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.8.4/video.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/videojs-contrib-hls.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-overlay/1.1.4/videojs-overlay.min.js"></script>
(function(window, videojs) {
        var player = window.player = videojs('player',
              {
                html5: {
                  hls: {
                    overrideNative: !videojs.browser.IS_ANY_SAFARI
                  },
                  nativeAudioTracks: false,
                  nativeVideoTracks: false
                },
                  liveui: true
                });
        overlay_content = '<div class="myOverlay"><h2>Live</h2></div>';
        player.overlay({
            overlays: [{
              start: 'loadstart',
              content: overlay_content,
              end: 'playing',
              align: 'top-left',
              showBackground: false
            }, {
              start: 'pause',
              content: overlay_content,
              end: 'playing',
              align: 'top-left',
              showBackground: false
            }]
          });
      }(window, window.videojs));



<video id="player"  class="video-js vjs-theme-sea vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered vjs-fluid" controls preload="auto" playsInline
        poster="Poster_Img">
        <source
          src="src"
          type="application/x-mpegURL">
</video>
```

It is working on desktop but on Android when I try to reposition the video progress bar it doesn't work.

I did enable the overridenative but still it doesn't work on android