# liveui option of videojs seeking is not working on Chrome browser of android (rest all platforms its working good)

Tags: javascript, android, web, video.js, live-streaming

I am unable to see the liveui seek bar in android.
As given in official documentation of videojs ;
"Note: This user interface will not work on Android due to the native live HLS implementation not supporting seekable ranges during live streams. We recommend overriding the native hls implementation with @videojs/http-streaming; this will make the new liveui work."

But I coundnt find anything to do the same.

These are the options which i have given.

```
var options = {
    preload: true,
    autoplay: false,                       
    controls: true,
    liveui: true,
    preloadWebComponents: true,
    techOrder: [ 'chromecast', 'html5' ],
    controlBar: {
        'liveDisplay': true,
        'pictureInPictureToggle': false,
        'subsCapsButton': false,
    },
    html5: {
         vhs: {
           overrideNative: true           //overrideNative: !videojs.browser.IS_SAFARI
         },
         nativeAudioTracks: false,
         nativeVideoTracks: false
       },
   
};'''
```

git hub similar question : https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/6789#issue-673460551

Stack Overflow similar question : [liveui of videojs seeking is not working on Chrome browser of android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63264598/liveui-of-videojs-seeking-is-not-working-on-chrome-browser-of-android)

https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-live.html
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xs3bP.png

Comment: What _might_ be happening - just guessing without a [mcve] - is the HLS stream is already loaded by the video elelement before initialising Video.js, so VHS is not used. If you are using a `<video>` el, try changing it to `<video-js>`.

Comment: The issue is resolved. The source was added in <video>, I removed and gave it in a player function It worked.  Here it is,       
``this.src({
            src : "----------" ,
            type: "application/x-mpegURL",                                                            
        });``